# How to connect tables in database first project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've created a database code-first in my MVC-project:

```
public class FrisorContext : DbContext
{
    public FrisorContext(): base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }
    public DbSet<Frisor> EntriesFrisor { get; set; }
}
```

This table contains 2 properties, one for `name` and one for `ID`. I would like to add another table containing these peoples schedules. In management studio, I can create that table (containing a primary key that connects it to the first table) and the data for the schedule. But how do I go about to create that second table in VS?

Comment: Your question is a little bit unclear. Do you follow any kind of tutorial or something? You can create the schedule table/entity pretty much like you've created the `Frisor` entity. If you have created the first then you should use the same technique to create the second. Maybe you have problem with the relation or something else, but it sounds to me like "how to create an entity".

Comment: Thanks for answering. So I need to create a new class and a new databaseconnection for every table i want to add?

Comment: No. You need to create all your entities and then add each entity in your `FrisorContext` class like you've done with `public DbSet<Frisor> EntriesFrisor { get; set; }`. Here is a simple tutorial where you can learn the basics of `Code First` approach - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542

Comment: Thank you! I´ll have a look!

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the class for the Schedule.
2. Add a DbSet for the schedules.
3. Decide on the relationship between the entities.

   - For one to one relationships, add a property to each class that is the type of the other class.
   - For one to many relationships, add a property of type ICollection<>.  For example, if there are many Schedules to a EntriesFrisor, you would a property of type ICollection<\Schedule> to the EntriesFrisor class, and a property of type Schedule to the EntriesFrisor .